# ios Undo manager - reset to first undo

Tags: ios, reset, nsundomanager

I am developing an IOS app.
I need a functionality that includes undo and reset.
It seems quite simple to perform an undo on the last operation.
However I can't find any built in support for resting to the first stored undo operation.

My question is, how can I pop the first undo action and reset my view accordingly?
Thank you

Comment: What type of actions are you trying to undo?  Standard text editing, or something else?

Comment: I am undoing a uiview movement on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're doing, the implementation might be different, but [the documentation for NSUndoManager can be found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you just want to undo the last group of actions, call `undoNestedGroup`.

If you want to undo everything, you could make a `while` loop that tested `canUndo`, and if that returned `YES`, called `undo`.

Comment: the problem is that every undo is followed with an animation, I don't want to animate all the undo's on the list. Just the first operation stored

Comment: NSUndoManager can't do that.  You'll need to implement your own way to save the state you want to go back to, and then to go back to it.

Comment: can't I just pull the first action in the UndoManager's action list?